# how to know if i am losing precision on algebraic operations?

Tags: python, largenumber

everyone... i am using python 3 on ubuntu OS. 
there is a pecission limit for  algebraics operations? for example i am using an expression that sums the products of several factors. Example

```
      -  19 * a[15] * a[16]**5 
    -  19 * a[15] * a[18]**15 
    +  114 * a[15]**2 * a[18]**11 
    -  228 * a[15]**3 * a[18]**7 
    +  19 * a[15]**4 * a[16] 
    +  95 * a[15]**4 * a[18]**3 
    +  19 * a[16] * a[17]**8 
    + ...
```

Obviously the entire expression uses each element within the list called "a".

where

```
a = [402481529333452799737856, 584701242576216277385216, 381624405337102891352064, 149810598966570642309120, 39872669983907831087104, 7677351509657277956096, 1112790794949098209280, 124591361265902845952, 10959810498173202432, 765616198595219328, 42719502536872064, 1906692221880063, 67880221932168, 1912942704676, 42095054406, 707502567, 8765436, 75402, 402]
```

i don't know if i am loosing precission, my expected response (based in a theory) is `3667707174836348186431483911144` and the obtained is `3667707189516889659417305507748`, as you notice the diference is very small (in contrast with the size of the numbers in the intermediate operations) and for this reason i think i am loosing precission in the compute task.
i can't give so much information.. my apologize.
so the question is... is possible to lose precission in pure python; if i use different large numbers, affected by basics operations (addition,substract,product,etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're operating entirely with integers, then no, you won't lose precision.

If your algebraic operations are only on rational numbers and you avoid taking roots of numbers, you can use the [`fractions`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) module and also avoid losing precision.

Otherwise, you'll lose precision unless you structure your operations to fall into one of the above two cases.

Comment: i am sure that i work with integers... but when the list called "a" has little integers (and to be honest not so much little than the given in my example) in every case i obtain the same number... the expression is made from products and sums , there is no other operations. but the entire expression is stored in a file and then read by a function that uses "eval"... this can be a problem?

Comment: @Alexis: Python can operate on integers of any size, so it's a problem with your code that uses `eval`.

Comment: my apologize, i 've find where is the mistake... the mistake is with another module related with the entire process (especifically numpy function called poly1d). in other words: my mistake was in the process to  get the values of the list. nevermind. thanks a lot!.